# Envio de dados em fluxo sobre Http em Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, http, stream

Existe algum meio de enviar dados sobre Http, mas ao invés de toda a informação de uma vez só, mandar uma parte de cada vez?

Por exemplo: Eu faço uma requisição Http para `GET /produtos`. Isso vai retornar todos os meus produtos (supondo que eu não coloquei um limite). Se eu tiver 500 produtos, isso vai tornar a requisição demorada, até que todos os produtos sejam processados-- e eu só poderei processar as informações do primeiro produto no cliente quando o servidor terminar de processar o último.

Eu gostaria de saber se, seguindo esse exemplo, há algum meio de o servidor enviar um produto por vez, num tipo de "streaming"-- assim, cliente e servidor estariam trabalhando simultaneamente, ao invés de um de cada vez.

(O código de cliente eu sei que é um só, em Javascript. O código do servidor, pra mim, é irrelevante, mas eu gostaria de saber ao menos qual é a técnica usada pra que eu possa pesquisar. Caso eu não consiga implementar no meu servidor, eu abro uma nova pergunta, pois essa deve ser apenas sobre a técnica usada e o código do cliente)

Esclarecendo: Eu estarei usando o Ajax, então sim, minha requisição será assíncrona. O que eu quero é fazer com que o servidor e o cliente trabalhem ao mesmo tempo, ao invés de o servidor fazer todo o trabalho dele antes que o cliente comece a trabalhar.

Numa requisição simples, o fluxo de trabalho seria basicamente esse:

```
Cliente faz requisição ->
 Servidor processa 500 produtos e envia ao cliente ->
  Cliente processa os 500 produtos
```

E minha intenção é fazer isso:

```
Cliente faz requisição ->
 Servidor processa um produto e envia ao cliente (e repete o processo até que não hajam mais produtos) ->
  Cliente processa um produto assim que o recebe (e aguarda por mais até que acabem)
```

Comment: Você poderia trabalhar com uma fila que dispararia requisições AJAX enquanto houverem itens a serem enviados. O disparo das novas requisições, a partir da segunda, poderiam, inclusive, estar associados ao clique de um botão, como os "Mais..." do plugin social de comentário do Facebook.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Eu pensei nisso, mas achei que seria bem gambiarra. Por isso perguntei aqui, pra descobrir se existe um meio mais "certinho". Mas se não tiver, vou usar isso mesmo.

Comment: Não acho que seja gambiarra, mas se preferir pode também aplicar o conceito de paginação enviando offsets cada vez maiores a cada clique no botão, por exemplo.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto A ideia é muito boa, mas não envolve um "fluxo" como eu especifiquei na pergunta. Não estou dizendo que a ideia é inválida, mas paginação e fluxo são conceitos diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

A princípio o que você procura parece ser um [socket](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.sockets.php) [nesse link vai encontrar um exemplo de implementação em php](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.socket-accept.php), uma outra formar de resolver isso seria a paginação, trazer 50 registros por vez, fazendo o javascript receber dados e armazenar em um cache local até ter todo o conteúdo, mas exibir os primeiros 50 (usando o limite para consulta), nesse site você encontra exemplos de socket servidor e cliente. Você poderá implementar depois sobre usando tcp, upd e fazer até stream se quiser.

O socket vai trabalhar do lado cliente e do lado servidor, o servidor irá prover as informações enquanto o cliente irá se conectar no servidor para receber os dados. Esse tipo de transferência de dados pode user em TCP e UPD cada uma tem suas vantagens e desvantagens, O servidor é responsável por gerenciar a conexões um servidor pode ter de 0 a N clientes conectados o que vai limitar a quantidade de conexões no nível lógico é a quantidade de portas em cada ip que ele estiver escutando e a nível de hardware o capacidade do equipamento e o link. Ao trabalhar com socket é necessário ter atenção sobre a forma como será feito o gerenciamento de credências, para controlar o privilégio e o acesso. O socket é algo que pode ser implementado em qualquer plataforma hoje é possível encontrar socket inclusive em javascript.

Exemplo de socket servidor em php:

```
/*********function to check new order******************/
function get_new_order()
{
$con=mysql_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DATABASE,  $con);
$sql="select  OrderId from customer_order where order_Status='0' "; //0 for new order
$query=mysql_query($sql,$con);
if(mysql_num_rows(  $query)&gt;0)
{
return true;
}
else return  false;
}
/*************************************/
/********Socket Server*********************/
set_time_limit (0);
// Set the ip and port we will listen on
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 6789;
// Create a TCP Stream socket
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // 0 for  SQL_TCP
// Bind the socket to an address/port
socket_bind($sock, 0, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');  //0 for localhost
// Start listening for connections
socket_listen($sock);
//loop and listen
while (true) {
/* Accept incoming  requests and handle them as child processes */
$client =  socket_accept($sock);
// Read the input  from the client – 1024000 bytes
$input =  socket_read($client, 1024000);
// Strip all white  spaces from input
$output =  ereg_replace("[ \t\n\r]","",$input)."\0";
$message=explode('=',$output);
if(count($message)==2)
{
if(get_new_order()) $response='NEW:1';
else  $response='NEW:0';
}
else $response='NEW:0';
// Display output  back to client
socket_write($client, $response);
socket_close($client);
}
// Close the master sockets
socket_close($sock);
```

[nesse link irá encontrar um exemplo completo do socket em php](http://www.funphp.com/?p=33) e uso [outro exemplo interessante pode se encontrado no seguinte aqui](http://www.binarytides.com/php-socket-programming-tutorial/)

Comment: Creio que a solução ideal sejam sockets. Vou pesquisar um pouco. Poderia elaborar melhor a resposta? Se quiser, pode tirar a parte de paginação e focar nos sockets. Se eu resolver por isso mesmo, eu aceito a resposta.

Comment: @AndréLeria agora está mais completa, os links que estão na resposta devem esclarecer eventuais dúvidas, caso contrário, deixe um comentário.

Comment: Ok, vou demorar um pouco pra testar, e se der certo eu aceito a resposta até amanhã. Obrigado. :)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, a solução ideal para você será comunicação assíncrona. Em uma requisição assíncrona, não existe sincronismo entre as requisições, sendo assim, podemos enviar diversas requisições em paralelo, onde cada resposta retorna quando estiver pronta.

Fazendo algumas alterações no cliente e no servidor você irá conseguir o que deseja.

Exemplos

Cliente

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Produtos',
    async: true
}).done(function(data) {
    alert(data); //Deve retornar "Tudo certo"
});
```

Servidor

```
<?php
sleep(10);
echo json_encode("Tudo certo!!");
?>
```

Dessa forma você poderá enviar diversas requisições, e no seu caso, tratar no servidor quantas produtos retornar, mesmo que tenha 500, retorne algo significativo para popular o lado do cliente.

Por padrão o `$.ajax` trabalha de forma assíncrona, caso queira da forma síncrona basta setar o parâmetro `async` para `false`.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Eu já estaria usando o Ajax, desculpe se não deixei isso claro. Mesmo com essa solução, todo o processamento é feito no servidor antes de o cliente começar a processar alguma coisa. Minha intenção é fazer ambos processarem ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Então André, a ideia é o cliente processar o script mesmo que não tenha recebido o dado ainda, ele vai continuar executando o script, no lado do servidor você pode determinar quando que as solicitações estarão prontas, você seta um intervalo no cliente até que tudo esteja carregado.

Imagine o seguinte, entre na página, já enviei uma requisição e ele me retornou 10 produtos, envio mais 1 ele me retorna mais 10 e assim por diante, a quantidade você mesmo determina.

Comment: Sim, sim, isso eu entendo. O meu ponto é que o cliente não vai processar nenhum produto enquanto o servidor não terminar de processar todos.